# What is the correct to model inverse gamma distribution

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution

I tried to use below R code to model inverse gamma distribution (alpha=1,beta=1).
However, the resulting histogram is not alike the one plotted in the 
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution). Could anyone provide any hint about this? Thank for you help.

`v <- rgamma(1,1,100000)
 v <- 1 / v
 dv <- as.data.frame(v)
 ggplot(data=dv,aes(x=v)) + geom_histogram()`

Answer (score 1):

The line 
`v <- rgamma(1,1,100000)` draws one observation from a $\text{Gamma}(1,100000)$. You can't make a histogram of this, since you only have one point. Since you say you want to draw from an $\text{InvGamma}(1,1)$, you probably want

```
v <- rgamma(n=1000,shape=1,rate=1)
v <- 1/v
```

instead. Don't be afraid to check out the documentation for the parameter ordering for this function.